# Rodeo is not importing seaborn even it is installed in python

Tags: python, anaconda, rodeo

I am having the following Issue:

```
ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ed9806ce3570> in <module>()
----> 1 import seaborn as sns
ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run following codes in the anaconda prompt window.
Open the anaconda prompt window and run this

```
conda install -c anaconda seaborn
```

It install it and once you import seaborn as sns in Rodeo You are Not gonna get the following error anymore.

```
"SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<ipython-input-54-31269c32ce07>, line 1)
  File "<ipython-input-54-31269c32ce07>", line 1
    conda install -c anaconda seaborn
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
```

Good Luck